# iGraph Python, convert edge list to tuple and add.edges

Tags: python, igraph, edge-list

I have a Graph G1 with 50 nodes and 100 edges. All edges are weighted. I have created a list of edges (sorted by a pre-defined order, removing specific edges with large values), and they are indexed like:

```
Edgelist: [75, 35, 32, 1, ...]
```

I want to add the edges to a different graph G2 in batches of 10 (to save computation time), but add.edges seems to want a tuple list of vertex pairs. So,

1. How can I convert the Edge list above into a tuple list, e.g. [(40,2),(10,1),(10,11),(0,0),...]. I've tried a loop with G1.es[edge].tuple, but iGraph reads the [edge] variable as an attribute, whereas if you just write G1.es[75].tuple, it works fine.
2. How can I look up weights from G1 and add them to G2 in batches of 10?

Comment: Is "Edge List" above a list of edge IDs referring to G1?

Comment: Yes it is. I have posted below my solution, but maybe there is a way of speeding it up?

Comment: I have posted a possible implementation below as an answer.

Comment: Thanks - do you have an R implementation for generating tuples from edge ids?

Comment: Use `get.edgelist()` in R to get the full edge list and then simply index the list with the IDs of the edges you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to be aware that indexing `G1.es` with a single number will return an object of type `Edge`, while indexing it with a list of numbers will return an object of type `EdgeSeq`. `Edge` objects have a property named `tuple`, but `EdgeSeq` objects don't, so that's why `G1.es[edgelist].tuple` does not work However, you can do this:

   ```
   sorted_tuples = [edge.tuple for edge in G1.es[edgelist]]
   ```

   You can also extract the value of the `weight` attribute directly from the `EdgeSeq` object:

   ```
   sorted_weights = G1.es[edgelist]["weight"]
   ```
2. Here you can make use of the fact that if `G2` has M edges and you add m extra edges, then the IDs of these new edges will be in the range from M (inclusive) to M+m (exclusive):

   ```
   M = G2.ecount()
   m = len(sorted_tuples)
   G2.add_edges(sorted_tuples)
   G2.es[M:(M+m)] = sorted_weights
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1) Graph G1 has had unwanted edges deleted already. Edgelist is the edge order for G1.

```
tuple_list=[]
for e in G1.es:
    tuple_list.append(e.tuple)

sorted_tuples=[tuple_list[i] for i in Edgelist]
sorted_weights = [G1.es['weight'][o] for o in Edgelist]
```

2) Add edges - this can simply be looped for all edges in G1. Example below for first 10.

```
edges_to_add=sorted_tuples[0:10]
weights_to_add=sorted_weights[0:10]

G2.add_edges(edges_to_add)

for edge in range(len(edges_to_add)):
    G2.es[G2.get_eid(edges_to_add[edge][0],edges_to_add[edge][1],0)]['weight'] = weights_to_add[edge]
```

Edge weights are added individually, which is a little slow, but there doesn't seem to be a way of adding edge weights in a batch in iGraph